# mysqli int update syntax error

Tags: mysqli, sql-update

Im trying to update a field on my database but keep getting the message that my sqli code has a syntax error. I am unable to find that error, i prevously has On and Id in all caps but changed it incase it was reserved by mysqli (db.php just has my database details)

```
include ("db.php") ;    
    //  connect to the database to get current state
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "fail";        }
```

Also tried it as "On = 1"

```
    $sql = "UPDATE GreenLED SET On='1' WHERE Id=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

"On" aswell as "ON" are reserved by sql and so i had to change On to LOn